# Ubuntu dont start when reboot

Tags: unity, upgrade, 15.10, compiz, fsck

My Ubuntu don't start when reboot and show the following message:

How to solve the problem?

[image]

Comment: Boot into recovery mode, pressing SHIFT and holding until GRUB tree table appears. Choose Additional options and recovery mode.

Comment: @Mookey I've used this way but the problem is not solved.